# How to increment variable after X

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have some code which increments in 50s from 0, to a max value of 5000, e.g:

0, 50, 100, 150, 200 etc...

I'm trying to change the increment amount after 1000 to increment up in 100s instead of 50s and can't seem to figure it out, here's my code:

```
getLoanAmounts: function getLoanAmounts(start, end, active) {
          list = []
          for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            if (i % 50 === 0) {
              list.push({
                key: i,
                value: (String(i).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,'))
              })
            }
          }
          this.formData.ReqLoanAmount = active
          return list
        },
```

This is a Vue JS application, this passes in a starting value of 0, and an end value of 5000, at the moment it increments in 50s all the way up to 5,000, I'd like to change the increment after a certain value.

Comment: `if(i > 1000 && i % 50 === 0){increment by 100}else if(i % 50 === 0){increment by 50}`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

I have done it like, in a for loop. if the value greater or equal than 1000 increment 100 else less than 1000 increment 50.

```js
function calculate(start, end){
  
  for(var i=start; i<=end;){
  
    console.log(i);
    if(i >= 1000 && i % 100 === 0){
      //do your other calculations
      i += 100;
    }else if(i < 1000 && i % 50 === 0){
      //do your other calculations
      i += 50;
    }else{
      i++;
    }
  }

}

calculate(930,1500);
```

Comment: No point of branching "else { i++; }" because there is no logic to execute for that branch. From the question, it is apparent, the increment is either 50, or 100.

Comment: @fluidguid but we need to increment right. I haven't added it on for loop. so I added it inside it